# How can I use the defined filter function inside of an object? | Nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a filter dropdown in the header and when users apply the filters I want to run the assigned function according to their choices but I couldn't run it, I got "... is not a function" error.

Also, even if I solve this problem, I will probably have problems in applying more than one filter at the same time, I would be very grateful if anyone could offer a solution in the form of applying filters in multiple ways.

[image: Filters Dropdown]

Example Object:

```
const filters = [
  {
    section: 'Call Types',
    slug: 'call-types',
    type: 'multiselect',
    options: [
      {
        label: 'Inbound',
        slug: 'inbound',
        value: true,
        func: (data) =>
          data.items.filter((item) => {
            return item.className === 'ib'
          }),
      },
      {
        label: 'Outbound',
        slug: 'outbound',
        value: true,
        func: (data) =>
          data.items.filter((item) => {
            return item.className === 'ob'
          }),
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    section: 'Data Types',
    slug: 'data-types',
    type: 'multiselect',
    options: [
      {
        label: 'Sentiment',
        slug: 'sentiment',
        value: false,
        func: (data) =>
          data.items.filter((item) => {
            return item.d1 === 1
          }),
      },
      {
        label: 'Capture Fails',
        slug: 'capture-fails',
        value: false,
        func: (data) =>
          data.items.filter((item) => {
            return item.d2 > 0.5
          }),
      },
      {
        label: 'Audio Notes',
        slug: 'audio-notes',
        value: false,
        func: (data) =>
          data.items.filter((item) => {
            return item.d1 === 1 && item.d2 > 0.5
          }),
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    section: 'Others',
    slug: 'others',
    type: 'singleselect',
    options: [
      {
        label: 'Show All Agents',
        slug: 'show-all-agents',
        value: true,
        func: (data) =>
          data.items.filter((item) => {
            return item
          }),
      },
    ],
  },
]

exports.filters = filters
```

And here is the method I'm trying to run when users click to "Filter" button.

Timeline vue file:

```html
<template>
  <vis-timeline
    :groups="filteredData.groups"
    :items="filteredData.items"
  />
</template>

<script>
import { mapActions, mapState } from 'vuex'
import VisTimeline from '~/components/UI/VisTimeline.vue'
export default {
  components: { VisTimeline },
  computed: {
    ...mapState({
      callTimeline: (state) => state.agents.callTimeline,
      timelineLoading: (state) => state.agents.loading,
      filterOption: (state) => state.agents.filterOption,
    }),
    filteredData() {
      var filtered = Object.assign(
        {},
        JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.callTimeline))
      )
      return this.filterItems(filtered)
    },
  },
  methods: {
    filterItems(data) {
      if (this.filterOption) {
        this.filterOption.forEach((filter) => {
          filter.options.some((option) => {
            if (option.value) {
              return option.func(data)
            }
          })
        })
      }
      return data
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Header vue file:

```html
<template>
  <a-layout-header style="background: #fff; padding: 0">
    <a-dropdown
      :trigger="['click']"
      :visible="visible"
      @visibleChange="handleVisible"
    >
      <template #overlay>
        <a-menu>
          <a-menu-item-group
            v-for="filter in filters"
            :key="filter.slug"
            :title="filter.section"
          >
            <a-menu-item :key="filter.slug">
              <a-checkbox
                v-for="option in filter.options"
                :key="option.slug"
                :name="option.slug"
                :checked="option.value"
                @change="filterChanges"
              >
                {{ option.label }}
              </a-checkbox>
            </a-menu-item>
          </a-menu-item-group>

          <a-menu-divider />
          <a-menu-item key="buttons"
            ><div class="flex justify-between">
              <a-button @click="visible = false" type="danger" ghost
                >Cancel</a-button
              >
              <a-button @click="applyFilters" type="primary">Filter</a-button>
            </div></a-menu-item
          >
        </a-menu>
      </template>
      <div class="mb-1">
        <a-button type="primary">
          <div class="flex flex-row justify-center space-x-2 items-center">
            <a-icon type="filter" />
            <span>Filters</span>
            <a-icon type="down" />
          </div>
        </a-button>
      </div>
    </a-dropdown>
  </a-layout-header>
</template>
<script>
import { mapActions} from 'vuex'
import { filters } from '~/utils/Filters'
export default {
  name: 'DBHeader',
  data() {
    return {
      visible: false,
      filters: filters,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions({
      setFilterOption: 'agents/setFilterOption',
    }),
    handleVisible(flag) {
      this.visible = flag
    },
    filterChanges(e) {
      this.filters.forEach((filter) => {
        filter.options.some((option) => {
          if (option.slug === e.target.name) {
            option.value = e.target.checked
          }
        })
      })
    },
    applyFilters() {
      var filters = Object.assign([], JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.filters)))
      this.setFilterOption(filters)
      this.visible = false
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: The `...` in `... is not a function` is kinda cryptic. Can't help with a specific + scoped example on what you want to achieve here. Regarding: `I will probably have problems in applying more than one filter at the same time`, depends on how you want your filters to behave here.

Comment: @kissu Here is the error : TypeError: option.func is not a function at eval (index.vue?6ced:163:1)

Comment: So, what do you have in `option`?

Comment: Also, where is `filterItems`? Context is quite important.

Comment: @kissu for example, if the user ticked both inbound and outbound at the same time, it should return all data with both 'ib' and 'ob' className in the data. But only if inbound is selected it should be only className ===  'ib'

Comment: Alright, so it's an inclusive union. For that, look how to merge 2 arrays or alike, focusing on the vanilla JS aspect is the main thing to achieve here. `className` is a React thing btw, we use regular `class` in Vue.

Comment: @kissu I added the options object in the "Example Object" code, please see above :) `filterItems` is defined in methods{}

Comment: So...where is `filters`? External `.js` file? How have you imported it? Did you imported it somewhere in a `.vue`'s `data()` or somewhere else? Again: context. Less back and forth, the faster and more efficient for both of us. A [repro] is highly recommended, otherwise try to read your question from an external POV and see if you can understand yourself where the issue may be coming from. Also, [ask].

Comment: @kissu yes you are right, I have expanded the codes to answer all these questions and simplified them to leave only the parts containing this topic. You will probably understand the problem more easily now. For testing purposes, I import the sample filters from a js file in the header and use them in the filters dropdown, then I save the applied filters in the state with vuex and use them in the timeline vue file and update the data accordingly. Thanks in advance :)